# Handle registration process in the middle of an SP initiated flow

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, registration

Given that

- Salesforce is set as Identity provider
- a Salesforce community works as identity provider for the community users, and is allowed the self registration.

consider that a Service Provider initiate the SSO Flow (SP initiated SSO Flow)

there is anyway to handle in the middle of the flow, the registration of a new user, after that to continue the SSO flow and to return a valid SAML Assertion to the SP?

Can be implemented a process like:

1. the service provider ask to the IDP to authenticate the user
2. the IDP before to perform the authentication, handle the registration process
3. after the registration, the IDP authenticate the user and return to the SP a valid SAML assertion related to the authenticated user

I'm not finding indications about this type of process in any documentation.

Can anybody helo me?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's possible if you write a fair amount of custom code. Out of the box - no.

Comment: interesting, can you help me to find a general flow on how to implement this on salesforce? Thanks @identigral

Comment: Write your own SAML IdP (yes, in Apex) and login + registration pages that all work together and understand the state of the flow

Comment: :) ok.... understood! Thanks man @identigral